# Does double negation confirm or annihilate the original negation

Tags: négation, double-négation

I am trying to understand whether adding a second negation word to a sentence **confirms** the negation to **cancels** it out.

Take the sentence: *Il n'y a qu'un livre dans le sac* (1).
This can be translated as "There is only one book in the bag".

When we add the word *plus* to the negation as in: *Il n'y a plus qu'un livre dans le sac* (2), the meaning doesn't essentially change, at least it is not flipped: "There is only one book left in the bag". Exclusivity of the one book still holds.

Now when we use *pas* instead of *plus*, as in: *Il n'y a pas qu'un livre dans le sac* (3), the meaning changes completely: "There is not only one book in the bag". The exclusivity is actually negated.

Second and third sentence use two negation words, in addition to *ne*. However, while the second sentence doesn't negate the first, the third does.

Are all form of negation I used valid grammatically (namely sentence 2 and 3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your sentences are valid and usual French.

The third sentence indeed negates the first one :

(1) *Il n'y a qu'un livre*: there is just one book (i.e. there are no more books than that one)

(3) *Il n'y a **pas** qu'un livre*: there is **not** just one book (i.e. there are more books than that one)

In the second sentence, *plus* isn't there no negate anything but to add a piece of information:

(3) *Il n'y a plus qu'un livre*: there is just one book (and before, there was more)